# MarkerClustererPlus and nested clusters

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

What I mean to do is the following: Suppose you have in a certain area a number of transmitting-receiving stations (pylons) (5, for example), and two hundred customers connected wirelessly to them (40 to each on average).

I want first an icon to appear on that area showing the number 5 (number of stations), then on click event on this icon I want those 5 pylons icons to appear, and subsequently on click event on any of those icons all customers icons (only customers connected to the clicked pylon) to appear.

All this for many areas in my country. The question is: what are the basic steps I should implement to get the task accomplished? What I have done at the moment is simply define a cluster of those 5 stations so, by clicking on its icon, all stations are shown.

Should I now define new clusters, one for each station, each one containing customers connected to it? Or should I take a bottom-up approach, I mean, define a single big cluster of customers, and then move on? In such a case how should I proceed?

I am a newbie to HTML and Javascript ( and I am 66!!! ), nonetheless I am trying to accomplish a task by using those languages and [MarkerClusterePlus](https://github.com/mahnunchik/markerclustererplus) library. I need suggestions, please. Thanks to all.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the code you have so far? Ideally, you make a working example with the "code snippet" feature of the editor. This way people can see how far you are and also would not have to start from scratch when answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answering.
I have only done few modifications on the example code provided with the library, both HTML and JS.

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="oNet.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">      
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', oNet.init);
</script>

<div>
    Markers:
    <select id="nummarkers">
      <option value="6" selected="selected">6</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <strong>Tralicci Bari</strong>
  <div id="markerlist">

  </div>
</div>
<div id="map-container">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function $(element) {
 return document.getElementById(element); 
}

var oNet = {};
oNet.tralicci = null;
oNet.map = null;
oNet.markerClusterer = null;
oNet.markers = [];
oNet.infoWindow = null;

oNet.init = function() {
   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41, 16.38);
   var options = {
  'zoom': 6,
  'center': latlng,
  'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
oNet.map = new google.maps.Map($('map'), options);
oNet.tralicci = data.tralicci;

var numMarkers = document.getElementById('nummarkers');
google.maps.event.addDomListener(numMarkers, 'change', oNet.change);
oNet.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
oNet.showMarkers();
};
```

Please note that what here appears as "oNet" is "speedTest" in the distributed example code, and "tralicci" is equivalent to "stations".

**Data_BA.json**

```
var data = {  
"tralicci": 
[
    {"trl_id": "BA_01", "trl_nome": "1o traliccio", "longitude": 16.58, "latitude": 41.09, 
            "title": "Traliccio n.   1\nPotenza 15 KW\nAltezza 37.5 m\nClienti connessi: 40",
            "stato": "on", "altezza": 375}
    ,
    {"trl_id": "BA_02", "trl_nome": "2o traliccio", "longitude": 16.578, "latitude": 41.112, 
            "title": "Traliccio n.   2\nPotenza 18 KW\nAltezza 42.5 m\nClienti connessi: 42",
            "stato": "on", "altezza": 350}
    ,
    {"trl_id": "BA_03", "trl_nome": "3o traliccio", "longitude": 16.544, "latitude": 41.09, 
            "title": "Traliccio n.   3\nPotenza 12 KW\nAltezza 22 m\nClienti connessi: 34",
            "stato": "off", "altezza": 474}
    ,
    {"trl_id": "BA_04", "trl_nome": "4o traliccio", "longitude": 16.556, "latitude": 41.08, 
            "title": "Traliccio n.   4\nPotenza 16 KW\nAltezza 35 m\nClienti connessi: 47",
            "stato": "on", "altezza": 375}
    ,
    {"trl_id": "BA_05", "trl_nome": "5o traliccio", "longitude": 16.580, "latitude": 41.085, 
            "title": "Traliccio n.   5\nPotenza 20 KW\nAltezza 39 m\nClienti connessi: 42",
            "stato": "on", "altezza": 375}
    ,
    {"trl_id": "BA_06", "trl_nome": "6o traliccio", "longitude": 16.790, "latitude": 41.12, 
    "title": "Traliccio n.   6\nPotenza 15 KW\nAltezza 32 m\nClienti connessi: 54",
            "stato": "on-off", "altezza": 333}
```

I've done very little, as you can see. I use my own image as station image, different from the distributed m2.png.